# Getting "null or not an object error" while accessing options of a select list

Tags: javascript, select, null

I seem to get this `null or not an object` error over and over when I try to code in javascript. This is an simple example where I'm just trying to make a window pop up that displays the name of the option. How can I avoid getting this error when I'm coding?

The code returns this error in Internet Explorer:

> Error: '`document.forms.0.questions`' is `null` or not an object

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- HTML5 style -->
<head>
<title>Challenge Question</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
window.alert(document.forms[0].questions.pet.name);
/* ]]> */
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="get" >
    <select name="questions">
        <option value="pet" name="pet">What is your pet's name?</option>
    </select>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try `document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0].questions.pet.name`

Comment: @silentboy - DOM isn't loaded yet.

Comment: Oh! I misread your code. You cant access dom before dom loaded. Wrap your code in function. Then use window.onload event to run your code. Thanks to derek.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The element must be added to the DOM first, then you can access it. Now you're trying to access an element that does not yet exist :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Challenge Question</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="get">
        <select name="questions">
            <!-- Element is added here -->
            <option value="pet" name="pet">What is your pet's name?</option>
        </select>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        /* and can be accessed here, after it's added */
        console.log(document.forms[0].questions.options['pet']);
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Y2Fja/)

Comment: You mean the select element must be added to the DOM? How would I add it to the DOM?

Comment: @user2228537 - What he mean is the DOM isn't loaded yet when your code is executed. So run it *after* the DOM is loaded will solve the issue.

Comment: You're already adding it to the DOM, but the javascript runs before the element is added.

Comment: Now it says line 16 Error: console is not defined.

Comment: @user2228537 - It's because in IE you have to open up your console first before loading in your page.

Comment: Ok so you're saying for example I could put it in a function at the top and then call it from the html. Or put it in a javascript section after the html.

Comment: what is a console anyway? I've never seen code like that before. I'm in a javascript 1 class at college.

Comment: Yes, either you need a DOM ready function, like window.onload, DOMContentLoaded etc. or you have to add the javascript after the elements you are trying to access are loaded. The last option is usually the simplest and fastest. The console is opened with F12, and is there for debugging stuff like this.

Comment: so that console.log thing.... is that just what you use to check if something exists (or is loaded)?

Comment: It's a debugging tool. Browsers implement it differently, and in Firefox (with Firebug) and Chrome it can be used to display objects, profile loading and execution speed, log stuff, whatever really, and makes it a lot easier to debug as alerts only support strings.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested the code. It works fine.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function func1()
  {
    var index = document.getElementById("pet").selectedIndex;
    var value = document.getElementById("pet").options[index].text;
    alert(value);
  }
```

```
 <form action="get">
 <select name="questions" id="pet" onchange="if (this.selectedIndex) func1();">
    <!-- Element is added here -->
    <option value="pet" name="pet"  >What is your pet's name?</option>
     <option value="pet" name="pet"  >What is your pet's 1?</option>
  </select>
  </form>
```

Comment: I used that code and added another option with the value "test" and the name "test". The value that pops up in the window.alert statement is undefined. How would I make a window pop up that says the name or the value?